# Magento 2 Virtual Host site for Google Customer Reviews (google merchant center)

Tags: magento2

I have created my virtual host(magento226.com) [using this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) for magento 2.

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento226.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName magento226.com
        ServerAlias www.magento226.com
        ServerAdmin mohit.rane69@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento_226
        <Directory /var/www/html/magento_226>
           Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

which is working fine.

I want to verify Virtual host(magento226.com) on google merchant center/google search console but i keep getting this error

> Verification failed - We were unable to connect to your server.
>
> Claiming failed - You must verify your URL before you can claim it.

[image]

**1. Html File Method :-**

> Changes

I've downloaded this HTML file:`google4ef0b3cccc5bb7d2.html` and placed in my magento 2 root directory which is `/var/www/html/magento_226`

> Error

[image]

**2. Html Tag Method :-**

> Changes

Copy the meta tag below, and paste it into your site's home page. It should go in the `<head>` section, before the first `<body>` section.

`<meta name="google-site-verification" content="JZlP-i7XEbOg4JCeCVZTp9pEHIJIOPNNJBwmZsEbWI0" />`

> Error

[image]

**3. Google Tag Manager :-**

> Changes

I've pasted the given code in the `<head>` and the `<noscript>` in starting of the `<body>`

> Error

[image]

**4. Domain name provider :-** I'm using Virtual host so this option is useless for me.

I've tried almost all the methods but doesn't seems to work.

Please let me know if anyone have a solution.

Comment: is there a symlink in site-enabled? sites-available is not enough

Comment: www.magento226.com is not available. did you register the domain?

Comment: @PhilippSander i've created the virtual host instead. check the link "using this link" on first line

Comment: but how is google supposed to reach your host? you can't just create a virtual host you have to buy the domain.

Comment: ohh...right! but are you sure isn't there any way to make a google verify the virtual host? I mean is it possible to do with virtual host?

Comment: think about it. how do you expect google to reach your localhost.

Comment: you have a point.